# Will onCreate always be called before onBind? (For a service that isn't already running)

Tags: android, android-service

If I try binding to a Service using `Context.bindService()`, and that Service isn't already running/started, will I be guaranteed that the `onCreate` of that Service will definitely be called before `onBind`? I wasn't able to find any docs on the lifecycle of a Service, at least with respect to this question of which one of these two comes first.

If not, in which cases will `onCreate` be called before `onBind`? In the tests I've done, `onCreate` always seems to be called before `onBind`. But I need to be sure of this because I have some logic that could possibly fail if this order changes

In case it helps, I'm binding to this service to get a `Messenger` that I will be sending messages to. So practically, my question is *"can I be assured that `onCreate` will execute before any of my messages get handled by the service?"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `onCreate` will be called first. It will not be called if the `Service` is already running.

[image]

[Service overview docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Lifecycle)

[Bounded Service overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Lifecycle)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `onCreate()` callback will always be called first. From the docs:

> Clients can also use Context.bindService() to obtain a persistent connection to a service. This likewise creates the service if it is not already running (calling onCreate() while doing so), but does not call onStartCommand().